# Android double numbers formatting issue

Tags: java, android

I have question regarding formatting in Android, I have the following code which format a double number to have 2 number precision only, the code work well when the android device language is English when I change it for example to Arabic the App crash in the last line. when I debugged in both cases (En - Arabic) I found that the double value passed to the function is the same ex: 1.2040

```
public static Double getRoundedStringValueTo2Precisions(double value){
    // TODO: check how we can parse the values where the decimal separator is comma()
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.##");
    return Double.valueOf(df.format(value));
}
```

Comment: `DecimalFormat("#0.00");`..

Comment: @Satya if this is an answer submit it as one. Would love to give upvotes if correct :)

Comment: The answer didn't work I still got the following error :

02-11 14:16:19.375 6572-6572

AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "٠٫٠٠"

Comment: does not contain a parsable double..

Answer (score 0):

Try with `x = Math.round(x * 100.00) / 100.00`

And don't forhet to parse

```
double y = Double.parseDouble(z.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Sorry but I need to use the DecimalFormat class. why I got this issue when I change the language to Arabic.?

Comment: What do you mean the code of english file? the function that I mention above it's a apart of an App which works well when the android device language is english when I change the android device language to Arabic then the App crash in that line -> Double.valueOf(df.format(value)); 
Crash log:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "٠٫٠٠"    java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)  java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:269)              java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue now it works when I change the language device. here is the fix

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
df.applyPattern("#0.##");
String ss = df.format(value);
return Double.valueOf(ss);
```